# Handsontable highlights complete column based on validation

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I am trying to validate the cell on my handsontable setup through an ajax call, which is working fine.
Now i want that on load the script runs and highlight the invalid cell.

```
var forceRefresh = function(){
hot.validateCells(function(){hot.render()});
};
setTimeout(forceRefresh, 0);
```

I am using the above code on data load and validate cells.
The problem is when the validation run the whole column containing the invalid cell gets red (Invalid class).
Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Can you give an example ? (With a JSFiddle or something) And tell what version of Handsontable you're using ? Couldn't reproduce your issue..

Comment: I am using Handsontable 0.20.0. I am not able to create a Jsfiddle with the data i have because it is being checked by some third party software for validation based on my server data.